# Configuring DNS for domain hosted outside of OVH

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, ns-record

I have just moved my site from FastHost to OVH, but run into a problem.

`spreadsheet123.com` are transferred without any problems, at least I would like to think so, but `spreadsheet123.co.uk`, `spreadsheet123.biz`, .... , `spreadsheet123.us` are not.

I have changed the Name Servers on FastHost to the new NS, just as I did with `spreadsheet123.com` and created an A record with new IP, which is also the same as `spreadsheet123.com`, because all the rest of the domains used to redirect to the .com version. I have waited for over 72 hours now, but nothing is happening. I have checked the DNS propagation on whatsmydns.net, but the A record is still not showing up.

Please help as I am not sure what I have done wrong.

Comment: Give us the actual domains so we can take a look.

Answer (score 1):

You have two nameservers specified for your main domain, but only one of them is returning records.

```
whois spreadsheet123.com
Name Server: NS397093.IP-151-80-99.EU
Name Server: SDNS2.OVH.NET

dig @SDNS2.OVH.NET spreadsheet123.com
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;spreadsheet123.com.        IN  A

dig @NS397093.IP-151-80-99.EU spreadsheet123.com
;; ANSWER SECTION:
spreadsheet123.com. 86400   IN  A   149.202.18.80
```

For your alternate domains, I'm not getting records returned by either nameserver. I'd suggest contacting OVH support for the right set of nameservers to use.

Comment: I just have contacted them, they suggested to create all of the domains in Plesk and then redirect them via DNS, is it actually possible?

Comment: You can't redirect with DNS alone - you'd point the DNS at your server, and have Plesk serve up redirects. Plesk is a cancer and such systems are [deemed off-topic here](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8055/what-should-server-fault-do-with-questions-about-web-hosting-control-panels).

Comment: I have done it via Plesk, just had to add those domains as domain aliases and 301 them to the main

Comment: @AlexB OK, but SDNS2.OVH.NET is not returning any DNS records for your domains. You need to either get them to fix that or remove it as a nameserver.

Comment: how about now, I have just added secondary DNS parameters

Comment: Run `dig @SDNS2.OVH.NET spreadsheet123.com` in your Terminal. Not showing up for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to contact OVH about this issue. Have you test to ping your domain? What is the result? If it hasn't resolved to new IP address, then there is problem from you or OVH dns setting.